# validate if table exists while selecting and inserting SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hello I have a dynamic query like

```
SET  @template = 'SELECT x AS X,... INTO temporalTable FROM' + @table_name
```

Then I execute it

```
EXEC (@template)
```

- How do I validate if `temporalTable`
  already exists, if so, drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use information schema or `sp_help` function.

I would prefer [**information schema**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) since it's SQL ANSI and you can port the code to other databases:

```
select count(1)
  from information_schema.tables 
 where table_name = 'temporalTable';
```

[`sys.tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) is a SQLServer specific option similar to inforamtion schema that you can also explore.

Comment: Overkill: a query with an aggregate. COUNT(1) is superstition too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649

Comment: It's not wrong of course. It just offends the OCD part of me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('temporalTable') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE temporalTable
```

No need to query any tables or do any aggregations.

Comment: +1 Clearly a better option than my answer. But counting on the information schema should not be that bad either. After all, object dictionary is probably in memory all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='tablename') 
        SELECT 'tablename exists.' 
ELSE 
        SELECT 'tablename does not exist.'
```